# Drupal Coding - Menus - hook_menu is not generating menus

Tags: routes, hooks

While working on the layout of a new custom menu, I discovered that the hook_menu process is not working on my D7.12 local site.  As a test I enabled the Menu_example module and found that it will not generate menu items in the navigation menu, although it did a week or two ago.  So far I have reinstalled all Drupal 7.12 files and confirmed that the module file hook_menus are being read (using dsm).  I am at a loss as to what else can be preventing the menu links from being installed.

Does anyone have any similar experiences or suggestions on how to track this problem down to its source?

EDIT:
This code does not add a menu item in an empty menu called "Stuff":

```
function material_menu_menu (){
  $items['stuff/existing'] = array(
    'title' => '020000 Existing', 
    'page callback' => 'material_view' , 
    'page arguments' => array ('sum' , '020000 '), 
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM, 
    'menu_name' => 'Stuff',   
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'weight' => '2 ');
  return $items;
}
```

Comment: I think the `menu_name` would normally be case sensitive so it should be `'stuff'` rather than `'Stuff'` to match up with the menu's machine name. Also your code above doesn't `return $items;`...could either of these be the problem?

Comment: I did have return $items but forgot to add it in this text.  I'll check on case sensitivity, but that does not explain why the menu_example module is not working now.  I had it enabled in the navigation menu when I was preparing to work on this menu, but when I re-enabled it, it no longer shows up.

Comment: I changed the case without a change in the problem.  I have also flushed caches.  I sure do love these Drupal engimas!!!  :)

Comment: Yeah I didn't think that'd fix it but it was worth a shot :) The place to start debugging is in [`_menu_navigation_links_rebuild()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/_menu_navigation_links_rebuild/7) which builds up the menu links...it gets passed the menu router items built up from [`menu_router_build()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/menu_router_build/7) (which is where `hook_menu()` is called from). A bit of temporary debug code in that first function would be the best way to go I think

Comment: OK, some progress!  I added dsm's to both drupal functions and found that the menu item was being included.  Curiously, the menu_example menu finally showed up in the navigation menu.  I have no Idea why it took so many iterations of toggling the module on and off to finally get it to appear (at least 5 cycles).  I parts of drupal code cached so that whatever may have been causing the omission of the menu was not readdressed until I altered the code in the core module?

Comment: The 'stuff' menu item is also working, although I had also added some content in the page callback which had been empty before, so that may have changed things. However, while the menu item responds to its path in the URL (stuff/existing), it does not appear in the list of links for the menu in the admin/structure/menus/stuff page.  I was under the impression that that is where MENU_NORMAL_ITEMs were supposed to appear.  Can you confirm that?

Comment: @Clive  Please plug in an answer so I can give you credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The place to start debugging is in [`_menu_navigation_links_rebuild()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/_menu_navigation_links_rebuild/7) which builds up the menu links...it gets passed the menu router items built up from [`menu_router_build()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/menu_router_build/7) (which is where hook_menu() is called from). A bit of temporary debug code in that first function would be the best way to go I think.

To address your other question, I've just added a menu item to a module in exactly the way you've done and it's come up in the UI as expected. It sounds like you have something pretty unusual happening with your menus!